PDFsharp XFontStyle not loading properly
I am trying a basic Hello world program with PDFsharp in my .NET 8 application.
Dowloaded the nuget packages as below

PDFsharp version 6.0.0
System.Drawing.common version 8.0.4
System.Text.Encoding.CodePages version 8.0.0

I am getting issue in the  line that uses XFont. Below is the code
     Pdfdocument document= new PdfDocument();

     Pdfpage page = document.AddPage();
     XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
     XFont font= new XFont("Verdana",12,XFontStyle.Bold);

I am getting error as
'XFontStyle' does not contain a definition for 'Bold'.
PDF sample I am referring is https://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloWorld-sample.ashx

When using PDFsharp 6.0, you should use the 6.0 documentation and the 6.0 samples.
See also:
https://docs.pdfsharp.net/PDFsharp/Overview/Upgrade-to-PDFsharp-6.html?q=XFontStyle

The class XFontStyle was renamed to XFontStyleEx

